# how to add coverflow (dynamic view) to the main.xml

Tags: android, gallery, coverflow

I tried using [coverflow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) in my application 
i want to use the coverflow in a linearlayout with particular dimensions in my main.xml ..
i tried but im getting this error..

```
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.Coverflow_displayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at com.android.Coverflow_displayerActivity.onCreate(Coverflow_displayerActivity.java:48)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
07-27 19:43:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1111):     ... 11 more
```

here is my code which i tried

```
package com.android;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.CoverAdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Coverflow_displayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);

//      
//      CoverFlow coverFlow;
//      coverFlow= new CoverFlow(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

        coverFlow.setSpacing(-15);
        coverFlow.setSelection(5, true);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//      setContentView(coverFlow);
        coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(CoverAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("this happens only in india", "ok i know this position"
                        + position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Use this if you want to use XML layout file
    //  setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private FileInputStream fis;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,

        R.drawable.killers_day_and_age, R.drawable.garbage_bleed_like_me,
                R.drawable.death_cub_for_cutie_the_photo_album,
                R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,
                R.drawable.massive_attack_collected, };

        private ImageView[] mImages;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
        }

        public boolean createReflectedImages() {
            // The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
            final int reflectionGap = 4;

            int index = 0;
            for (final int imageId : mImageIds) {
                Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), imageId);
                int width = originalImage.getWidth();
                int height = originalImage.getHeight();

                // This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preScale(1, -1);

                // Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
                // We only want the bottom half of the image
                Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0,
                        height / 2, width, height / 2, matrix, false);

                // Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit
                // reflection
                Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,
                        (height + height / 2), Config.ARGB_8888);

                // Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
                // the image plus gap plus reflection
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
                // Draw in the original image
                canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
                // Draw in the gap
                Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap,
                        deafaultPaint);
                // Draw in the reflection
                canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage, 0, height + reflectionGap,
                        null);

                // Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the
                // reflection
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0,
                        originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap,
                        0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, TileMode.CLAMP);
                // Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
                paint.setShader(shader);
                // Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
                // Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
                canvas.drawRect(0, height, width,
                        bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180));
                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                mImages[index++] = imageView;

            }
            return true;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // Log.v("getCoutn(int count)", "" + mImageIds.length);
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // Log.v("getItem(int position)", "" + position);
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // Log.v("getItemID(int position)", "" + position);
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Use this code if you want to load from resources
            // ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            // i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            // i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            // i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            // return i;

            // Log.v("getview int position mImages", ""+position);

            return mImages[position];
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views depending on the
         * 'offset' to the center.
         */
        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            Log.v("getScale float ", " " + focused + " " + offset);
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
        }

        // View v=getView(position, convertView, parent);

    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_here"
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        >

     <com.android.CoverFlow
            android:id="@+id/coverflow"
            android:layout_width="700dp"
            android:layout_height="700dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you havnt set the view of the activity (`setContentView`) before mapping control.

Comment: i guess u r talking about this,..
setContentView(R.layout.main);
//      setContentView(coverFlow);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an error in your `onCreate()`. `setContentView(R.layout.main);` should be called before you try to assign coverFlow (`CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);`). Thats why coverFlow is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to set the view of your activity so that `findViewById` will get ID from that view and map the controls. so write

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` before mapping the control i.e.

```
CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers here. The problem is trying to initialize the widget even before calling the setContentView(). But I believe that the user is trying to follow the same thing because , he is not able to get the difference between setting a Content from a XML and creating a View in the code and setting it as the content.

In the above example, if you can see , the author tries to create a Coverflow view thorugh code here,

```
    CoverFlow coverFlow;
    coverFlow= new CoverFlow(this);
```

And then he has set this view using, `setContentView(coverFlow);`

But in our case, where we use XML generated resource,

The first thing is to map the xml to our Activity using `setContentView()`. Because only then the System will know that it has to look up for the resource fromn the very XML which we have provided to it using the `SetContentView()`. If not it will lead to NullPointerException since andorid will not find the resource as we havn'e specified where to look up.

So, for your case just follow the above answers and provide the

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

first, and then initialize your view with reference form it, like,

```
CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
```

Comment: Not a problem. Welcome always.. Instead of pointing out the mistake alone, i just wanted to explore how they actually vary. I hope this will be helpful for those who are new to this kind of concept.